# Python translate function

Tags: python, string, translate

How to use it? I have tried to run the code found as solution on codewars:
[image: codwars solution]

but I get error:

> TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

In documentation I have found it takes argument `table` which is `mapping` or `sequence`. (what is it?!)
To create it I can use `maketrans()` but how to put None there when as second argument it needs string with equal length?

```
tabl = string.maketrans("aeiouAEIOU", "          ")
string = string.translate(tabl)
```

I programme in Java and R and I must admit that python is very messy language.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 `translate` accepted 2 arguments, in Python 3 it only accepts one.

Comment: @stakowerflol the difference is that this was a major version change, which typically is backwards incompatible in software. Java has never had a major version change, it's still on 1.X. This has left a lot of warts hanging around in the language.

Comment: Technically, the Java version you see increasing the minor version number (i.e. 1.7 -> 1.8 -> 1.9). Minor version numbers imply no API breaking changes. Similar to Python 2.6 -> 2.7. Python 2.x to 3.x is a Major version change, and therefore is allowed have API breaking changes.